# PHP not generating txt files

Tags: php, html

After a lot of help from people on this website I have been able to get 99% of this script written, yet it is still not executing properly. Here is the code:

**PHP**

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET['W']) ){
    $url = md5($_GET['w']);
    if(!is_file('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt')){
        $fh= fopen('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', 'w');
        fwrite('1',$fh);
        fclose($fh);
    }else{
        $hits = file_get_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt');
        $hits++;
        file_put_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', $hits);
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="txt" name="w" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>

<p><?php echo $hits; ?></p>
```

For some reason it doesn't appear to be working. You can see a live demo here: http://www.colindunn.com/prints/index.php and a more thorough look at the code here: http://codepad.org/ZeTuj707

Looking at my server, it is not generating TXT files at all. Could this be a limitation of my host?

Comment: wouldent a db be better?

Comment: Most likely. But if I can get this to work, that would be fine for my needs.

Comment: First step: Activate error reporting to see what the problem is

Comment: Can you write text files on their own? Use `file_put_contents` in a php file of its own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution could be you have `name="w"` in lowercase and `$_GET['W']` in uppercase.

This solution is untested!

EDIT

To fix the problem in the comment below swap the fwrite peramaters around

```
fwrite($fh,'1');
```

https://www.php.net/fwrite

EDIT 2

You are not creating the `$hits` variable that is used later in your display the first time a visit is made to a site.

See below code which sets up `$hits`, inserts it in a file, and leaves to to be used later.

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET['W']) ){
    $url = md5($_GET['w']);
    if(!is_file('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt')){
        $fh= fopen('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', 'w');
        $hits = 1;
        fwrite($fh, $hits);
        fclose($fh);
    }else{
        $hits = file_get_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt');
        $hits++;
        file_put_contents('/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt', $hits);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That seemed to do something. I am now getting the error message: Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in [~]/prints/index.php on line 6

Comment: @colindunnn you have to reverse the parameters in fwrite, it is first the file resourse got from fopen, and then the string                                                                   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how the `fwrite()` line should be written

Comment: The error is no longer appearing, but you will notice the hit counter doesn't display 1 on the first visit: http://www.colindunn.com/prints/index2.php?w=colindunn.com

Comment: Answer updated again to include `$hits = 1` for the first time a visit is made

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
if(isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET['w']) )
{
    $url = md5($_GET['w']);
    $filename = '/hit_counters/'.$url.'.txt';

    $hits = (int)file_get_contents($filename);

    // if the file could not be read, $this will be false
    if ($hits === false) $hits = 0;

    $hits++;

    // if the file did not exist, it will now be created with a value of 1 in it.
    file_put_contents($filename, $hits);
}
```

That is, if you may write in the directory `/hit_counters/`.

But in fact you shouldn't be using this code. You should use a database. What if two users (relatively) simultaneously execute this script?

Comment: You are completely right. However, this is intended only as a proof of concept. I am (clearly) not a programmer, so practical issues like that are not really important. Thank you very much for your help.